# Unbold post title in blogger

Tags: css

I'd like to unbold my post titles in blogger but it's not working through CSS or customise>post title (when I click the B bold button the font appears even bolder) I have a custom font but even when changed to arial or others it's still bold. I've tried the following

```
.post-body, h1.title, h2, .description, body, h3.post-title {
  font-family: 'arial', sans-serif;’
font-weight: normal;
}

.post title {
font-weight: normal !important;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: update the html or checking in which browser

Comment: I don't quite understand?

Comment: share the html code and let us know which browser you are checking. add screenshot if possible. hope you are clear

Comment: Is there a typo maybe? The second rule should be .post-title with a hyphen?

Comment: html: 
h3.post-title, .comments h4 {
  font: $(post.title.font);
  margin: .75em 0 0;
}

checkin in safari

Rafi - yes sorry that was a typo I originally had a hyphen